# Does the Battle Dancer's AC Bonus feature stack with the Arcane Duelist's Apparent Defense feature?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, multi-classing, prestige-class, stacking

The Battle Dancer class has a feature with an AC bonus, which states (*Dragon Compendium Volume I*, p. 28):

> **AC Bonus (Ex):** When unarmored and unencumbered, the battle dancer adds her Charisma bonus (if any) to her AC. She uses the captivating and confusing movements of the battle dance to evade her foes' attacks.
>
> (...)
>
> These bonuses to AC apply even against touch attacks or when the battle dancer is flat-footed. She loses these bonuses when she is immobilized or helpless, when she wears any armor, when she carries a shield, or when she carries a medium or heavy load.

While the [Arcane Duelist](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/re/20030224a) prestige class's Apparent Defense feature says:

> **Apparent Defense (Ex):** Due to trickery and force of personality, the arcane duelist adds her Charisma bonus to her Armor Class, in addition to her Dexterity bonus. Conditions that cause the arcane duelist to lose her Dexterity bonus to Armor Class also cause the arcane duelist to lose this bonus.

Does the Battle Dancer's AC Bonus feature stack with the Arcane Duelist's Apparent Defense feature?

It seems to me that they should stack, as the features are named differently, and work differently too. But I'm not exactly sure and would like a RAW answer, if possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do bonuses of the same type stack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/63601/do-bonuses-of-the-same-type-stack)

Comment: I asked this question mostly due to the discussions about Monk & Battle Dancer...
But now that I think about it, the problem there was that they both had the same Class Feature, it just worked off of different stat...
While this case is two Features working off of Cha, and increasing AC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the SRD:

> In most cases, **modifiers to a given check or roll stack (combine for a
>   cumulative effect) if they come from different sources and have
>   different types (or no type at all)**, but do not stack if they have the
>   same type or come from the same source (such as the same spell cast
>   twice in succession).

In your example,

- They have different sources, and
- They have no type

Therefore, **they stack.**

Even taking narrative into account, they are described differently - one coming from "captivating and confusing movements", the other from "trickery and force of personality".

*(Also note that when you are flat-footed, you will lose the Arcane Duelist's bonus, but keep the Battle Dancer's.)*